# Trouble installing mailcatcher gem on Windows

Tags: ruby, rubygems, mailcatcher

After an windows update starting mailcatcher for development purpouse did not work anymore.

I updated ruby using RubyInstaller for Windows, but trying to install mailcatcher i get a giant fail that indicates somethign basic is at miss

I switched to a beta mailcatcher version because of this:
https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher/issues/539

Here are some of the errors:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>gem install mailcatcher --version=0.9.0.beta2
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mailcatcher:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9.1/ext/fastfilereader
C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9.1/ext/fastfilereader
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20230621-29048-1p4cu8 sitelibdir\=./.gem.20230621-29048-1p4cu8 clean

current directory: C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9.1/ext/fastfilereader
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20230621-29048-1p4cu8 sitelibdir\=./.gem.20230621-29048-1p4cu8
generating fastfilereaderext-x64-mingw-ucrt.def
compiling mapper.cpp
compiling rubymain.cpp
In file included from C:/Ruby32-x64/msys64/ucrt64/include/wtypes.h:8,
                 from C:/Ruby32-x64/msys64/ucrt64/include/winscard.h:10,
                 from C:/Ruby32-x64/msys64/ucrt64/include/windows.h:97,
                 from C:/Ruby32-x64/msys64/ucrt64/include/winsock2.h:23,
                 from C:/Ruby32-x64/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/win32.h:36,
                 from C:/Ruby32-x64/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/internal/dosish.h:38,
                 from C:/Ruby32-x64/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/defines.h:78,
                 from C:/Ruby32-x64/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:25,
                 from C:/Ruby32-x64/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby.h:38,
                 from rubymain.cpp:26:
C:/Ruby32-x64/msys64/ucrt64/include/rpcndr.h:64:11: error: reference to 'byte' is ambiguous
   64 |   typedef byte cs_byte;
      |           ^~~~
In file included from C:/Ruby32-x64/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/memory_resource.h:38,
                 from C:/Ruby32-x64/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.1.0/string:58,
                 from C:/Ruby32-x64/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from C:/Ruby32-x64/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from C:/Ruby32-x64/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.1.0/ios:44,
                 from C:/Ruby32-x64/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.1.0/ostream:40,
                 from C:/Ruby32-x64/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.1.0/iostream:41,
                 from rubymain.cpp:22:
C:/Ruby32-x64/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.1.0/cstddef:69:14: note: candidates are: 'enum class std::byte'
   69 |   enum class byte : unsigned char {};
      |              ^~~~
C:/Ruby32-x64/msys64/ucrt64/include/rpcndr.h:63:25: note:                 'typedef unsigned char byte'
   63 |   typedef unsigned char byte;
      |                         ^~~~
C:/Ruby32-x64/msys64/ucrt64/include/rpcndr.h:397:170: error: reference to 'byte' is ambiguous
  397 |   typedef void (__RPC_API *CS_TYPE_TO_NETCS_ROUTINE)(RPC_BINDING_HANDLE hBinding,unsigned __LONG32 ulNetworkCodeSet,void *pLocalData,unsigned __LONG32 ulLocalDataLength,byte *pNetworkData,unsigned __LONG32 *pulNetworkDataLength,error_status_t *pStatus);
      |                                                                                                                                                                          ^~~~
C:/Ruby32-x64/msys64/ucrt64/include/rpcndr.h:398:119: error: reference to 'byte' is ambiguous
  398 |   typedef void (__RPC_API *CS_TYPE_FROM_NETCS_ROUTINE)(RPC_BINDING_HANDLE hBinding,unsigned __LONG32 ulNetworkCodeSet,byte *pNetworkData,unsigned __LONG32 ulNetworkDataLength,unsigned __LONG32 ulLocalBufferSize,void *pLocalData,unsigned __LONG32 *pulLocalDataLength,error_status_t *pStatus);
      |                                                                                                                         
 
make: *** [Makefile:240: rubymain.o] Fehler 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.2.0/eventmachine-1.0.9.1/gem_make.out

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Comment: Is that a 32 or 64 bit installer?

Comment: It is the 64 Bit Installer with DevKit